# Convert numpy array of integers to 12 bit binary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I neeed to convert a np array of integers to 12 bit binary numbers, in an array format. What would be the best way to go about doing so?

I've been a bit stuck so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is what I have to convert an integer to binary:

```
def dec_to_binary(my_int):
"""

Format a number as binary with leading zeros"""
if my_int < 4096:
    x= "{0:12b}".format(my_int)
    return int(x)
else:
    return 111111111111
```

Comment: I am able to turn a single integer to binary, but can't figure out how to iterate through the np array and change values without errors: see below -

Comment: ** See above **

Comment: Just what do you mean by "binary number"? There is no such python object.

Comment: Why would you want to create an array of 12 bit binary? If this is an attempt to save memory, be aware that solutions involving strings of `'1'` and `'0'` actually use much more memory (12 bytes) than 16 bit ints (2 bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight correction (replace `12b` with `012b`):

```
def dec_to_binary(my_int):
    """   
    Format a number as binary with leading zeros
    """
    if my_int < 4096:
        return "{0:012b}".format(my_int)
    else:
        return "111111111111"
```

Example:

```
In [10]: n_array = np.array([123,234,234,345, 4097])

In [11]: map(dec_to_binary, n_array)
Out[11]: 
['000001111011',
 '000011101010',
 '000011101010',
 '000101011001',
 '111111111111']
```